# I need help finding the time complexity of this function

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

If someone could step through the function and explain how they would go about finding the time complexity I would really appreciate it. I'm still a bit lost when it comes to this.

```
int exp2 (int a, int b)
{
        if (b==1)
        return a;
    Else
        return a*exp2(a,b-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**O(b)**.

Notice that the function will repeat **b** times, doing a single operation (multiplication).

```
(1) exp(4, 20) = 4 * exp(4, 19)
(2) exp(4, 19) = 4 * exp(4, 18) 
(3) exp(4, 18) = 4 * exp(4, 17)  
...
(b) exp(4, 1) = 4
```

Comment: So, the way i saw it and maybe you can tell me why I'm wrong is that the function itself will need to be repeated b-1 times based on the value of b, obviously, but then once that's finished it needs to recursively multiply a with the value that the subsequent functions returned... am I overthinking it?

Comment: You measure the complexity based on the number of operations that the function will have to do according to the input.

Comment: In this case, the operation you are doing is `*`. How many `*` will you do in `exp(4, 20)`? As I shown in the example, it will be `b - 1` operations of `*`, hence the complexity is `O(b - 1)` = `O(b)`.

Comment: Thanks much for the answer and explanation!

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent of raising `a` to the power of `b-1`. Number of operations used is `b-1`. It increases in proportion to `b` so complexity is `O(b)`.